# how to retrieve data stored in android apps

Tags: applications, storage

I am using Moto G. downloaded a video through android app.I am able to play video through app. Where to tracethis video in phone memory and get this video for using in other devices

Comment: It would help if you mention the name of the app and whether or not it caches its data.

Answer (score 1):

Find name of your app it will be like com.awesome.me
After you know name of application
Go to android/data/com.awesome.me/
This directory will be in your internal storage
U might see a lot of files and folders with different extensions
If its a video start looking for files with size of around 10 mb or more when you find it try to open with video player
After you find ur video
Change extension to video extensions
Copy it to your folder of choice
And enjoy

Sorry i am weak in English
N try x-plore file manager
Its  easy to use
Note:this is not advertising its just a suggestion/opinion